# SCNNode maintain -z velocity after applying torque

Tags: ios, physics, scenekit

When i apply torque to a node that is traveling along the -z axis in a forward motion either by setting velocity directly or applying force the node rotates on its y axis as intended but continues along the world's -z axis so it is then travelling sideways.

How do I get the nodes velocity to change with the torque so it is always moving along it's own -z axis

Comment: we are not oracles add more info about your problem ... images with description are preferred (at least by me) because they are the best for breaking the language and terminology bariers

Comment: I apologise for a rushed question. I'll try explain more and when I'm back at my computer I'll add pictures if needed. For now picture car on the road traveling forward, then come to a bend in the road. I apply torque to turn the car, the car rotates but still continues forward in a straight line not following the road around the bend. I should add that the car is just an example and scnvehicle is useless in my case

Comment: what and how do you store parameters like: position, velocity, acceleration, mass ...  how do you update/iterate it with time. what kind of physics you use? (Newtonian,D'Lambert,Relativistic?). The most likely scenario is D'Lambert. so rotation and movement are two separated things. You have to apply torque for rotation and also apply some acceleration to change the velocity vector direction. the size and direction depends on the propeling/turnig system of your simulated object (car has blocking friction on dis-aligned wheels, rocket has thrusters,...) so it matters if it is a car or not.

Comment: I am using scenekit so all parameters are properties of the SCNNode. Initially I had set velocity directly through these properties, then I tried applying force. Also as of right now I have friction set to 0 and restitution set to 1 so there's no loss in velocity during simulation.
I am using renderer to apply torque when buttons are pushed.
I had the idea of attaching another physics body behind with a hinge so when forces are applied off centre it would cause the leading body to turn but hopefully maintain velocity in its own -z axis. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: yes it does make sense, that mean SCN uses D'Lambert principle so: movement and rotation are separate things. to achieve the direction change you have to apply force/acceleration perpendicular to the force that create the torque and apply it on the center of mass (or use direct velocity or acceleration change) the size is dependent on the rotation speed, object mass and speed. see equations for centripedal rotation/movement and try to experiment on that (I am no SCN user so I cant test it or verify)